# Openssl Keystore generation command fails with Error reading password from BIO and Error getting password

Tags: openssl, opensuse

I am trying to install a third-party certificate, while generating the Keystore the command is returning **Error reading password from BIO and Error getting password**

I am using the below command to generate the Keystore.

**openssl pkcs12 -export -in hostcert_response.cer -inkey private.key -out hostkeystore.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile hostcert_response.cer -caname root -chain -passin file:$temp_password_file -passout file:$temp_password_file >/dev/null**

Note- $temp_password_file is the temp file where I am storing the user input password for the certificate.

Any help is appreciated